# Strict locators in codeception

Tags: selenium, webdriver, codeception

Is there any performance difference between the strict locators and less strict ones?
For example:

```
$i->click(['css' => '#id']);
$i->click('#id');
```

Answer (score 1):

I have experimented and there is a slight performance gain if the locator is stricter. However, the time benefit is negligible. In some cases is better to use less strict ones in order the locator to be more maitainable.